# Collision Speed at which seatbelts become ineffective

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, acceleration, estimation

In a car, what is the speed at which if you were to crash (eyeballs-out) your deceleration would be so high that your seat belt becomes ineffective and that you would've die whether or not you actually wore a seat belt?

Note. Not sure whether the question is more biology or physics

Comment: I'd wager that irrespective of speed its how high you accelerate during the crash or ultimately how high the jerk is.

Comment: Can there still be people in 2018 who don't get it ?!?!? Hint : Formula One drivers wear safety belts (harnesses), why would anyone else not do it ?  Deaths and serious injuries in crashes are reduced significantly when a seat belt in used compared to the results of crashes where idiots did not use belts.  No wheeled vehicle has ever existed where a seat belt would not improve the odds the surviving a crash and reduce the likelihood of serious injury.

Comment: Well sorry you don't understand @StephenG, but my question is saying is there a speed where you would die whether or not you actually wore a seatbelt. What is it's limits?

Comment: No two crashes (or people) are alike.  You can't make such absolute statements unless you're willing to settle for an upper limit that's just silly (e.g. 10,000 km/hr).  As far as I know the [fastest car crash with a survivor](http://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/world-records/fastest-car-crash-survived) wearing a safety belt (i.e. a harness) was at 981 km/hr (jet powered car) and I doubt someone would survive such a crash without restraint harness ("seat belt") but the seat belt doesn't *guarantee* your survival at any speed.  No practical upper limit exists IMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You die at much less severe impacts from collision if you don't have any seat belt. Also, many collisions are not single impact. For example, many are partial impact followed by rolling, hitting the ditch, getting hit by the third vehicle in the collision, etc. These are often of lower impact acceleration but at odd angles. And you really don't want to hit the windshield or get thrown out.

So seat belts won't be obsolete. They simply won't protect against all possible collisions. That's true at quite low speeds. Say you get hit by a gas truck.

This is why seat belt design has continued to work on the issue. So you get head rests. You get 3-point instead of 2-point. You get air bags. You get child safety seats, and warnings not to put them in a seat with an air bag. You get a variety of restraint tech such as belts that sense the collision, tense the belt, then reduce the maximum force to reduce injury. Or internal car structures intended to crumple out of the way and use up some of the collision energy.
And external crumple zones intended to do the same.

And, not too long from now, we will start to see computer driven cars become very popular. Then the seat belt will be intended to keep you from messing with the controls.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Still I wanted to find out what is the limit to your average three point seat belt on a eye-ball out head on collision into a stationary immovable object. Where technology stands what's the limit in which if you crash there is little hope of surviving.